# Rock Paper Scissors Game (Menu Method)

Tags: java, methods

So as it says in the title, I am trying to create a RPS Game with a Menu as a Method, the thing is I don't know how to call inputs from that menu at any point.
For a better idea, this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String player1choice, player1Name;
        int mainMenu,subMenu;
        String again;
        player1Name = "";


    welcomeBanner ();
    mainMenu = getMenu (keyboard);


    if (mainMenu == 1)
    {
        keyboard.nextLine();
        player1Name = getAName (keyboard);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) System.out.println();
        main (null);
    }

    if (mainMenu == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome "+player1Name); //add name input
        subMenu =getsubMenu (keyboard);
        System.out.println("You have chosen: "); //add option chosen

        System.out.println("Cpu has got, It's a Tie!");//cpuChoice add


    }

    if (mainMenu == 3)
    {
        keyboard.nextLine();
        String exitRequest;
        System.out.print("Are you sure you want to exit? (Y/N): ");
        exitRequest = keyboard.nextLine ();
        if (exitRequest.equals("y") || exitRequest.equals("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (exitRequest.equals("n") || exitRequest.equals("N"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) System.out.println();
            main(null);
        }

    }
}
static void welcomeBanner()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*        Welcome To The Rock, Paper, Scissors Game         *");
    System.out.println("*----------------------------------------------------------*");
    System.out.println("*     Created by: Jonathan Gutierrez, and I am NoxBot!     *");
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
}
static int getMenu (Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    int playermenuChoice;
    System.out.println("1. Enter Player Name");
    System.out.println("2. Play a Game");
    System.out.println("3. Exit Application");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    playermenuChoice = aKeyboard.nextInt();
    return playermenuChoice;

}
static int getsubMenu (Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    int submenuChoice;
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 for Paper");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 for Scissors");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
    submenuChoice = aKeyboard.nextInt();
    return submenuChoice;
}
static String getAName (Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    String player1Info;
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    player1Info = aKeyboard.nextLine ();
    return player1Info;
}
static String computerChoice ()
{
    String cpuChoice;
    cpuChoice = "";
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    int cpu = randomNumbers.nextInt (2) + 1;
    switch (cpu)
    {
        case 1:
        cpuChoice = "Rock";
        break;
        case 2:
        cpuChoice = "Paper";
        break;
        case 3:
        cpuChoice = "Scissors";
        break;
    }
    return cpuChoice;
}
```

So when the player chooses option 1, program asks to enter the name of the player, and i want to use that input at any point (most specifically when mainMenu ==2). How can i do that?

EDIT: this is my new code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String player1choice, player1Name, subMenu;
        int mainMenu;
        String again;
        player1Name = "";

        welcomeBanner ();
        mainMenu = getMenu (keyboard);

    if (mainMenu == 1)
    {
        keyboard.nextLine();
        player1Name = getAName (keyboard);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) System.out.println();
        welcomeBanner ();
        mainMenu = getMenu (keyboard);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Welcome " + player1Name);
        System.out.println("");

    }

    if (mainMenu == 2)
    {

        subMenu =enterPlayersChoice (keyboard);
        keyboard.nextLine();
        String cmpu = computerChoice ();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)

        if (subMenu.equals(cmpu))
           System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        else if (subMenu.equals("rock"))
        if (cmpu.equals("scissors"))
        System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You win!!");
        else if (cmpu.equals("paper"))
        System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You lose!!");
        else if (subMenu.equals("paper"))
        if (cmpu.equals("scissors"))
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You lose!!");
        else if (cmpu.equals("rock"))
        System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You win!!");
        else if (subMenu.equals("scissors"))
        if (cmpu.equals("paper"))
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You win!!");
        else if (cmpu.equals("rock"))
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors. You lose!!");
        else   System.out.println("Invalid user input.");
        System.out.println("");


    }

    if (mainMenu == 3)
    {
        keyboard.nextLine();
        String exitRequest;
        System.out.print("Are you sure you want to exit? (Y/N): ");
        exitRequest = keyboard.nextLine ();
        if (exitRequest.equals("y") || exitRequest.equals("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (exitRequest.equals("n") || exitRequest.equals("N"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) System.out.println();
            main(null);
        }

    }
}
static void welcomeBanner()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*        Welcome To The Rock, Paper, Scissors Game         *");
    System.out.println("*----------------------------------------------------------*");
    System.out.println("*     Created by: Jonathan Gutierrez, and I am NoxBot!     *");
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
}
static int getMenu (Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    int playermenuChoice;
    System.out.println("1. Enter Player Name");
    System.out.println("2. Play a Game");
    System.out.println("3. Exit Application");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    playermenuChoice = aKeyboard.nextInt();
    return playermenuChoice;

}
public static String enterPlayersChoice(Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    String input = "";
    System.out.print("You have a choice of picking rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    input = aKeyboard.nextLine();
    String inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
    return inputLower;
 }
static String getAName (Scanner aKeyboard)
{
    String player1Info;
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    player1Info = aKeyboard.nextLine ();
    return player1Info;
}
public static String computerChoice ()
{
    String cpuChoice;
    cpuChoice = "nothing";
    Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    int cpu = randomNumbers.nextInt (2) + 1;
    switch (cpu)
    {
        case 1:
        cpuChoice = "rock";
        break;
        case 2:
        cpuChoice = "paper";
        break;
        case 3:
        cpuChoice = "scissors";
        break;
    }
    return cpuChoice;
}
```

}
To finish this i want the game to display a message whether player wins or lose, but it is being skipped (mainMenu ==2) any ideas?

Comment: You're setting `player1Name` twice. Once in the method, and again in the return. After which you call `main(null)`. I don't think you should be calling `main(null)`. The 5th statement into your main method is `player1Name = "";`

Comment: i was calling main(null) so i can re-desplay the welcomeBanner() and mainMenu(), i havent think of another solution. i thought if i assign player1Name = ""; i would be able to make the program compile. This is just a sketch of what i want

Comment: Give me one moment, and I can help you restructure this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of rearranging your existing application in a different manner. Some of the major changes include making all methods non-static except the main method, and creating a RockPaperScissorsNew object for the application's point of entry. I've also added class variables so you don't need to pass your Scanner around as an object to all of your methods.

To answer your original question of how you're able to re-use the input entered by the user, the solution I provided is to retain that information within the class variable.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RockPaperScissorsNew {

    //Class variables
    Scanner keyboard;
    String player1choice, player1Name; //Name will be stored here.
    int mainMenu,subMenu;

    public RockPaperScissorsNew()
    {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
        welcomeBanner();  //Display the welcome banner once.
        while(true)       //Repeatedly display the main menu.
            getChoice();  //Get the user's choice
    }

    public void getChoice()
    {
        int choice = -1;          //Set choice to fail first.
        while (choice > 3 || choice < 0)  //Wait until user choice passes.
        {
            choice = getMenu();  
        }
        if (choice == 1) { //Choose your sub option.
            getAName();    // Get the user name.
            System.out.println("Your name is " + player1Name); //Saved
        }
        if (choice == 2)
            getsubMenu();
        if (choice == 3)
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public void welcomeBanner()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*        Welcome To The Rock, Paper, Scissors Game         *");
        System.out.println("*----------------------------------------------------------*");
        System.out.println("*     Created by: Jonathan Gutierrez, and I am NoxBot!     *");
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public int getMenu ()
    {
        int playermenuChoice;
        System.out.println("1. Enter Player Name");
        System.out.println("2. Play a Game");
        System.out.println("3. Exit Application");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        playermenuChoice = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine().trim());
        return playermenuChoice;
    }

    public int getsubMenu ()
    {
        int submenuChoice;
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for Paper");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for Scissors");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
        submenuChoice = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine().trim());
        return submenuChoice;
    }

    //This method has been changed to use the class variable, and no longer
    //returns a string.
    public void getAName ()
    {
        //String player1Info;
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        player1Name = keyboard.nextLine ();
        //return player1Info;
    }

    public String computerChoice ()
    {
        String cpuChoice;
        cpuChoice = "";
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        int cpu = randomNumbers.nextInt (2) + 1;
        switch (cpu)
        {
            case 1:
            cpuChoice = "Rock";
            break;
            case 2:
            cpuChoice = "Paper";
            break;
            case 3:
            cpuChoice = "Scissors";
            break;
        }
        return cpuChoice;
    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        new RockPaperScissorsNew();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though i really like this, u missed a few things that are required, i just posted an edit :) still got the answer when i saw your code